# Converting two loops to single LINQ query using C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, for-loop

I searched some links here to change nested loops to single Linq, I tried using those, part of code is not working, I need some expert guidance to fix this,

**UPDATE 1:**

I guess wasn't clear in my explanation, the loops works fine! as expected, I am getting correct results, but I am doing optimization, instead of using two loops i need the same code to be converted to single linq.

here is the code :

```
foreach (var ob in all_request_list.Where(x => x.StartDate != x.EndDate)) {
    int consq_dates = ob.EndDate.DateDiff(ob.StartDate);                
    for (int i = 0; i <= consq_dates; i++) {
        combined_list.Add(new { ShiftID = ob.ShiftID, SkillID = ob.SkillID, EmployeeID = ob.EmployeeID, AssignDate = ob.StartDate.AddDays(i), ProfileID = ob.ProfileID });
    }
}
```

I have problem adding increment variable `i` to `ob.StartDate.AddDays(i)`.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? What are the types handled by `combined_list`? I'm pretty sure that you can't add the anonymous type that you're using in `Add` call to that list. The only ways may be a `List<dynamic>` or `List<object>`. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: why would you ever want to add 0 days to a date?

Comment: @Neil To start at that day maybe (Inclusive range)

Comment: Have updated the explanations, please have a look at it.

Comment: @Neil, add 0 will take the current day. the above code works absolutely fire, there are no errors, I need to optimize the code using linq.

Comment: @Manjuboyz I did not expect it to break.

Comment: _...the loops works fine! as expected_. Changing `for` loops to `LINQ` will not affect on performance. Pure `for` loops is always faster then `LINQ` version of same loop and in some cases `LINQ` can worse readability

Comment: What kind of optimization you are looking for? It is very unlikely to get Linq code to be faster than regular loop. So clearly you are not looking for speed... But what else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var items = from ob in all_request_list
            where ob.StartDate != ob.EndDate
            let consq_dates = ob.EndDate.DateDiff(ob.StartDate)
            from i in Enumerable.Range(0, consq_dates + 1)
            select new { ShiftID = ob.ShiftID, SkillID = ob.SkillID, EmployeeID = ob.EmployeeID, AssignDate = ob.StartDate.AddDays(i), ProfileID = ob.ProfileID };
combined_list.AddRange(items);
```

But: You've code that works. You understand that code. Why do you wan't to change that? BTW: Your two loops will be faster than that linq.

Comment: Oh! really, I didn't know that two loops will be faster than linq, is there a way to check which runs faster ? am not sure this question lies in this scope.

Comment: Use stopwatch to check

Answer (score 2):

***You can use the following `Linq`:***

```
var items = all_request_list
    .Where(x => x.StartDate != x.EndDate)
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(0, x.EndDate.DateDiff(x.StartDate) + 1)
        .Select(y => new { ShiftID = x.ShiftID, SkillID = x.SkillID, EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID, AssignDate = x.StartDate.AddDays(y), ProfileID = x.ProfileID }))

combined_list.AddRange(items);
```

What it does exactly is Creating an `IEumerable<>` of results for each item in the `all_request_list.Where` using [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) (This is the part which replaces your `for` loop), than flattens it using the [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

It might be better than a `for` loop in the terms of readability/maintainability but keep in mind that `Linq` [usually slower than plain loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044400/linq-performance-faq) (***tl;dr: Understand what `Linq` does internally and what it will do in your case***).

Comment: You miss closing bracket here `Enumerable.Range(0, x.EndDate.DateDiff(x.StartDate)`. And you should add `+1` to calculate last date

Comment: I'm pretty good in linq but I prefer using query syntax. My problem seeing your code is: are you sure that you can access `x` in the `.Select(y => ...` - lambda?

Comment: You can because `x` is defined for the scope of the `SelectMany` which ends only in the end of the `Select` line.

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference, I don't like reading query syntax so I try to avoid them.

Comment: Oh sorry. I missread the closing brackets. Sorry. My fault. Now it's clear. I thought that you're using a where than a selectmany and finally a select. But the select was inside the selectmany.

Comment: Yes it does. Thx. Our answers are equivalent. I know that. OP should pic one.

Comment: Sorry about previous reply! yes it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what error you're getting, but it could be due to the fact that certain functions cannot be executed *inside* a linq statement, since it internally translates it to sql. Try this:

```
foreach (var ob in all_request_list.Where(x => x.StartDate != x.EndDate))
        {
            int consq_dates = ob.EndDate.DateDiff(ob.StartDate);                
            for (int i = 0; i <= consq_dates; i++)
            {
                var newDate = ob.StartDate.AddDays(i);
                combined_list.Add(new { ShiftID = ob.ShiftID, SkillID = ob.SkillID, EmployeeID = ob.EmployeeID, AssignDate = newDate , ProfileID = ob.ProfileID });
            }
        }
```

If it still gives you an error, could you specify what error you're receiving, such as the name, type, etc.

Comment: How do you know that it will be translated into SQL? OP doesn't say anything about SQL or databases.

Comment: What they mean is that LINQ gets translated into an expression. Imagine trying to write a for loop inside the expression block of an if statement `if(for(...)) { }`. The compiler wouldn't accept it. LINQ expressions are the same thing, just really spread out.